# How do I use epa-sign-file and not disrupt functionality of the file with the ASCII-armored signature

Tags: org-mode, major-mode, pgp, gpg, epa

I want to be able to gpg sign specific files, specifically org-mode file.

However, doing `M-x epa-sign-file RET filename.org` will create the file `filename.org.asc` and introduce new text in that file that might disrupt functionality of the file if used as the original file.
It seems cumbersome to publish both files.

Is there a way to make sure that the file `filename.org.asc` can be used as the original file.

**Minimal working example**

example `filename.org`:

```
* Should be loaded

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "hello world")
#+end_src
```

This will be after `M-x epa-sign-file RET filename.org` -> `filename.org.asc`

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

* Should be loaded

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "hello world boom")
#+end_src
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

iQEcBAEBAgAGBQJWTNPCAAoJED51s3ZWaq4/D5cH/3ztdd3YZxOu/XCG7bOEZuQa
jcxKrXiwhmLhKoC4a9tmgCJVDryy4tdSci2WUHoIxJ0vN3BFI2txFm7aoxGpIQCk
Dxjczy2RtHeN1+N+wBsxeQq5EeZ0A/7c9+eJQmub2GopAWe6D7rggCAEvnFNFcdN
LcZTo1o/jrKa63Q/KPmN+Y2E2nC4KjICn+SvaVUy2noZzS7c6ofw2dsY7YP915Ng
hs/38aITDMOpapzphQ0/VkJRDAard8U5jGmCIOMGwXyC7NIYVYB69Cdruo8uz/HA
xzl8QpMz/tv7qOLyQJLZYCPAglrt5ZGA19XAuKHqMgfvS563UCmRJdcLuGZaj58=
=3jbG
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Comment: Why not create an MD5SUM of your .org file, then create an encrypted signature of the MD5SUM, MD5SUM.sign, and share the 3 files whenever necessary? That way, your .org file will stay the same.

Comment: @Nsukami_this is a really great answer. A side effect is that I can sign multiple files in one go and it can be easily done in the dired buffer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an Emacs related problem but, one of the solution could be:

- create a SUM of your .org file,
- then create an encrypted signature of the SUM file, named SUM.sign,
- and finally, share the 3 files whenever necessary

That way, your .org file will stay the same.

Comment: sha1 or sha256 would be better than md5.

Comment: @db48x I was just showing the idea, but yes, answer edited.